# Getting error 'Invalid type: EmailMessage'

Tags: email, class, error, apex-email-service, emailmessage

I have create one class which implements `Messaging.InboundEmailHandler`.
It was working fine until now, but now I am getting `Invalid type: EmailMessage` while editing the class.
And, when testing the same I am getting `FATAL_ERROR Internal Salesforce.com Error`

Comment: Sounds like you're running into the issue of _name shadowing_. This happens when you have a class, a method, or a variable that uses the same name as something else (`EmailMessage` in your case). You need to search your code for where you did this, and change those identifier names (or if it's a class, delete and re-create it with a more carefully chosen name).

Comment: The problem was that enhanced email was disabled.